# Why is folder efstmpwp located in C drive even when I am ciphering D drive in Window 8?

Tags: hard-drive, command-line, windows-8, cipher

I am trying to wipe all the deleted data out of my laptop using `cipher` command on Window 8. When I use `cipher /w:C`, the folder `efstmpwp` is created in C drive, which supports the cipher process. But when I use `cipher /w:D`, this folder is still created in C drive, not D. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

C is usually the main partition of a Windows installation. As almost everything system related is located on that drive/partition, it's only natural for the cipher service to locate it's temporary files there. As far as i'm aware, there is also no flag/command to change this behaviour.

Hope that explains it :)

Comment: If the temporary file is in C, how is it possible for cipher to use this file to wipe the data in D? Do you mean that D and C are actually different partitions of the same disk?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a colon after the `D`. So:

```
Cipher /w:D:
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).